# Dart cannot generate "prisma_client.g.dart" from Prisma client

Tags: json, flutter, sqlite, dart, prisma

I have a flutter application that I want to use SQLite database with Prisma ORM based on the work done at https://prisma.pub.

everything seems to work fine until I run the command `dart run build_runner build` then it fails to generate the dart prisma client to work with the Prisma generated Client.

This is the prisma schema I'm working with for now

```
generator client {
  provider = "dart run orm"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = "file:./source.db"
}

model User {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid())
  email     String   @unique
  firstname String?
  lastname  String?
  userpass  String
  role      String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  status    Boolean  @default(true)
  userID    String?  @unique
}
```

on running
`npx prisma generate`,

the prisma client is successfully generated and expects this file

`part 'prisma_client.g.dart';`

however when I run

`dart run build_runner build`

I get the following error:

```
$ dart run build_runner build
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 296ms
[INFO] Reading cached asset graph completed, took 89ms
[INFO] Checking for updates since last build completed, took 800ms
[INFO] Running build completed, took 21ms
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 46ms
[SEVERE] json_serializable on lib/src/generated/prisma/prisma_client.dart (cached):

Could not generate `fromJson` code for `equals`.
To support the type `InvalidType` you can:
* Use `JsonConverter`
  https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonConverter-class.html
* Use `JsonKey` fields `fromJson` and `toJson`
  https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonKey/fromJson.html
  https://pub.dev/documentation/json_annotation/latest/json_annotation/JsonKey/toJson.html
package:class_wise/src/generated/prisma/prisma_client.dart:567:30
    ╷
567 │   final StringFieldRefInput? equals;
    │                              ^^^^^^
    ╵
[SEVERE] Failed after 83ms
```

Since i would be adding more models, I would like a permanent solution to this so that I dont have to manually code the toJson of every unavailable data type conversion error that will arise.

I have searched onlne but it seems there is very little engagement with this stack combination, any help in any form will be very much appreciated.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what he said :

Unfortunately, Prisma for Dart does not currently support Prisma 5.x version (due to huge changes). Also you should see my tweets, I am now committed to my normal life due to the bankruptcy of my company. I'm really sorry, I don't know when I will have time to come back and continue to maintain it, but I have always paid attention to this project. Once I get my debt out of the way, I'll go back to open source and continue maintaining Prisma for Dart.

you can check this link https://github.com/odroe/prisma-dart/issues/259